# Saving data from an online page into local string variables

Tags: javascript, android, string

Is it possible to pull strings out of, for example a < td> tag found within a table on an online page and then store them into local string variables?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

First you can make regular http request to the web site.

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet post = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String htmlBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

Then you can use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) library to traverse and extract whatever you need from the html, you can search by tags (div,td, etc), id's, whatever you need.

Actualy it has it's own http requests too,

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
```

Comment: Thanks. So are these 2 different approaches? Or are they one solution together?

Comment: Ok so i tried your first code (i had to put the second block into a try, catch), but now its force closing. Any ideas?

Comment: If you are trying the first one, you got to use the AsyncTask class, which invokes new worker thread to make the http request call, since you are not allowed to make calls on the UI Thread.

Try the second one, I think it invokes it's own worker thread so that you don't have to worry about it.
The first line gets the web site content, the second one it's just an example on how can you use it after have the content

Comment: My apologies. Won't happen again. :)